# Regex help needed to parse and extract property from an expression tree

Tags: regex, regex-group

Here is a valid property tree expression (it can be recursive):

rootProperty:(prop1, prop2, subProp1:(prop1,subSubProp1:(prop1,prop2,etc),prop3), prop3, etc)

So in effect a property can have many properties and sub-properties.
From this expression I would like to capture the following:

- rootProperty
- prop1
- prop2
- subProp1:(prop1,subSubProp1:(prop1,prop2,etc),prop3)
- prop3

I tried few approaches but could't get the repetitions working recursively. Hence seeking help.

Thanks
Kannan

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: And, regular expressions are generally not suited for recursive structures, so this is probably not the best approach anyway.

Comment: hi Joanis, I agree, I think regex could be a wrong choice for this recursive structure. I may have to find alternative way to traverse the property tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a regular language due to recursion (balanced parens), so a regular expression might not be what you need. But assuming you know what you are doing:

```
([^:(), ]+)(?::\(((?R)?(?:, ?(?R))*)\))?
```

First we capture the name of the property: one or more characters that are not `:(),` .

```
([^:(), ]+)
```

A property may or may not have a subtree, so the next part is the optional subtree:

```
(?:           <--- do not capture
   :          <--- literal ':'
   \(         <--- literal '('
      ...     <--- some stuff inside
   \)         <--- literal ')'
)?            <--- it is optional
```

The stuff inside captures a list of properties:

```
(             <--- do capture
 (?R)         <--- recursively match a property
 (?:          <--- do not capture
    , ?       <--- comma followed by optional space
    (?R)      <--- recursively match another property
 )*           <--- any number of comma separated properties
)             <--- end capture
```

For your example input:

```
Input:
    rootProperty:(prop1, prop2, subProp1:(prop1,subSubProp1:(prop1,prop2,etc),prop3), prop3, etc)
Match 1:
    rootProperty:(prop1, prop2, subProp1:(prop1,subSubProp1:(prop1,prop2,etc),prop3), prop3, etc)
    Group 1:
        rootProperty
    Group 2:
        prop1, prop2, subProp1:(prop1,subSubProp1:(prop1,prop2,etc),prop3), prop3, etc
```

You could then recursively match the second group of each match for capturing the properties of a subtree. There should be a way to get the backtracking information so you don't need to do this, but I don't know how.

```
Input:
    prop1, prop2, subProp1:(prop1,subSubProp1:(prop1,prop2,etc),prop3), prop3, etc
Match 1:
    prop1
Match 2:
    prop2
Match 3:
    subProp1:(prop1,subSubProp1:(prop1,prop2,etc),prop3)
    Group 1:
        subProp1
    Group 2:
        prop1,subSubProp1:(prop1,prop2,etc),prop3
Match 4:
    prop3
Match 5:
    etc
```

Then,

```
Input:
    prop1,subSubProp1:(prop1,prop2,etc),prop3
Match 1:
    prop1
Match 2:
    subSubProp1:(prop1,prop2,etc)
    Group 1:
        subSubProp1
    Group 2:
        prop1,prop2,etc
Match 3:
    prop3
```

And finally:

```
Input:
    prop1,prop2,etc
Match 1:
    prop1
Match 2:
    prop2
Match 3:
    etc
```

https://regex101.com/r/WAXrFd/2

Comment: Thanks a lot, this would work for me. I haven't used '?R' before. If anything other than leaf properties, I will be calling the parse function recursively to parse the nested sub property. I will try this in my code. Thanks again.

Comment: Wow, I am amazed at this solution. With recursion like this, we're now talking context free grammar. Modern RE libraries in programming languages have long since not actually been technically regular, but this is taking it an amazing step further. I need to learn this tool, but wow, that's REs on serious drugs!