# Regex for nested comments

Tags: regex, nested, expression, comments

Is there any regex rule that detects nested comments?
With "nested commnets" I mean something like this:

```
/* something /* something */ something  */
```

I don't want a rule that detects something like this:

```
/* something inside /* something inside */ something inside */ something outside /*something inside */
```

I want the comment after `something outside` to be a new detection.
Thank you!

Comment: In general, regular expressions are not good at matching nested patterns.

Comment: Although you may be able to do it with the recursion feature in PCRE.

Comment: This answer to a different question uses recursive regular expressions. A similar solution might work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66881353/3216427

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you're using regex engine like PCRE(Perl, PHP etc.) which supports recursion.

You may use this regex to capture the nested comments:

```
\/\*(?:(?!\/\*|\*\/).|(?R))*\*\/
```

- `\/\*` match `/*`
- `(?:...)` non-capture group
- `(?!\/\*|\*\/).` any character that doesn't form a `/*` or `*/`
- `|` or
- `(?R)` recurse the entire rule, which is the entire structure of `/* ... */`
- `\*\/` match `*/`

check the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/bhJue9/1/)

But without recursion, you can only achieve it with the logic brought by whatever the programming language you are using.

---

Also if you want to capture the contents outside of the comments, you may try

```
(\/\*(?:(?!\/\*|\*\/).|(?1))*\*\/)|((?:(?!(?1)).)+)
```

They are stored in different groups.

Check the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/eB2Fsd/1/)

Comment: If you want to capture multiline comments including linebreaks, you can replace the `.` with `[\S\s]` to get: `\/\*(?:(?!\/\*|\*\/)[\S\s]|(?R))*\*\/`